# 'Request' object has no attribute 'add_data'

Tags: python-3.6, urllib

I am getting the error as below while used add_data module from import urllib.request.

I have googled it and came to know that add_data is no longer available from python 3.4.

Is there an alternative way to add data with python 3.6?

```
'''
 import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
 req = urllib.request.Request(url)
 data = ###some data###
 req.add_data(json.dumps(data))
'''
```

Getting error as below:
'Request' object has no attribute 'add_data'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly assign the data without any function calls.

```
req.data = json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me! Just passed data with bytes as well (req.data=bytes(json.dumps(data), 'utf-8'))

Answer (score 0):

[You can set data in the urllib.request.Request now.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request.data)

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
data = "###some data###"

req.data = data
```